# How to create and save gtk interface

Tags: c, gtk, glade

I'm using glade and gtk with c language to create an application. I have a glade file and I need to create a list of widgets, to clarify I need to create a variable number of line and in each line I need to put some widgets, labels, button etc.
How can I modify my glade file and made the modification permanent from c code?

Here my code but it doesn't show the grid and doesn't save the modifications in glade file:

```
void on_Pagamento1_clicked() {

GtkBuilder      *builderPagamento; 
GtkWidget       *window;
GtkGrid         *g_grd_linea;
GtkWidget       *g_cbt_mattino = gtk_combo_box_text_new_with_entry ();
GtkWidget       *g_lbl_nome = gtk_label_new ("Nome");
GtkWidget       *g_lbl_cognome = gtk_label_new ("Cognome");
GtkWidget       *g_lbl_eta = gtk_label_new ("Eta");
GtkLayout       *g_lyt_layout;

int i;

builderPagamento = gtk_builder_new();
gtk_builder_add_from_file (builderPagamento, "glade/pagamento.glade", NULL);

window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builderPagamento, "pagamento"));

gtk_builder_connect_signals(builderPagamento, NULL);

g_lyt_layout = GTK_LAYOUT(gtk_builder_get_object(builderPagamento, "layout"));
gtk_combo_box_text_append_text (g_cbt_mattino,"35.00");
gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(g_lbl_nome), "Prova");

g_grd_linea = gtk_grid_new();
for(i=1;i<=4;i++){
    gtk_grid_insert_column (g_grd_linea,i);
}
gtk_grid_attach (g_grd_linea,g_lbl_nome,1,0,1,1);
gtk_grid_attach (g_grd_linea,g_lbl_cognome,2,0,1,1);
gtk_grid_attach (g_grd_linea,g_lbl_eta,3,0,1,1);
gtk_grid_attach (g_grd_linea,g_cbt_mattino,4,0,1,1);
gtk_layout_put(g_lyt_layout,g_grd_linea,0,0);

g_object_unref(builderPagamento);

gtk_widget_show(window);  
}
```

EDIT:
I think I've solved my problem: Since the window is not the  main window and it is created only by pressing a button, I open  the file and I modify the XML code of glade from c code, so when I press the button it will show the modified glade file and consequentially the modified window

Comment: paste your code.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve your problem (seems to me) is to design pages, which you make invisible if not wanted. I.e. make all the forms you need, put each of them into a Box, and only show() one of them.

If the forms are not very different, say only few items change, you can do this in the same `GtkGrid` or `GtkBox`: only show the fields you need to show. In a VBox or HBox, items that are not visible do not occupy any space.

If you want to do (prepare) this from Glade, set the items you want to hide as invisible, then change their properties to visible by code.

If you want to hide/show several items at a time, you can group them in a separate `GtkFrame`, `GtkGrid` or `GtkBox` again, and then apply hide/show on the Frame or Box.

Comment: This is a good idea, but my problem is that I don't know when I create the window how many lines I will need to add.

Comment: At least in Python, you add dynamically rows to GtkGrids, or items to GtkBox. So that shouldn't be a problem. Just define a GtkBox in glade, put in the items you *do* know about. Then afterwards you can add more by code. It has been a while since I used C, but I suspect it's possible there too.

Comment: Ok, but if I add items by code do they will be saved in glade file or they will just appear because the code impose it?

Comment: No, if you create items by software, that has no effect on the glade file at all (which is normally read only once, at startup). The new items will only exist till the program stops working (or if you destroy the items by software again). Next time the program starts, it will read the original Glade file again. If necessary, you could save the configuration of the new items in a separate file.

Comment: I think I've solved my problem but not using GTK. I post my solution in the question post so if someone else need to dinamically add or remove items can look at this solution